# Easiest way to add a function to existing class

Tags: python, wrapper, shelve

I'm using the python's built-in shelve module to manage some simple dictionaries. The problem I'm having is I want to use `with shelve.open(filename) as f:`, but when I try it claims DbfilenameShelf has no attribute `__exit__`.

So, I'm guessing the easiest way to do this is to wrap it in another class and add an `__exit__` function to that wrapper. I tried this:

```
class Wrapper(shelve.DbfilenameShelf):
    def __exit__(self):
        self.close()
    def __init__(self, filename, writeback=False):
        shelve.DbfilenameShelf.__init__(self, filename, flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False)
```

But when I tried to instantiate the wrapper like so: `wrapped = Wrapper(filename)` it tells me I'm giving it an invalid argument.

Error as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "<input>", line 5, in __init__
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\anydbm.py", line 85, in open
return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\dbhash.py", line 18, in open
return bsddb.hashopen(file, flag, mode)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\bsddb\__init__.py", line 364, in hashopen
d.open(file, db.DB_HASH, flags, mode)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

Comment: We need the exact error message. Also, don't context managers need an `__enter__` method as well?

Comment: I got this error as well. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with having too many open files on one's system -- encapsulating it with `closing()` reduces the open file overhead... User agf's solution solved it for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't subclass it. Python comes with a tool for automatically calling `close()`, [`contextlib.closing`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
from contextlib import closing
with closing(shelve.open(filename)) as f:
    # your 'with' block here
```

will automatically call the `close()` method of the object returned by `shelve.open(filename)` at the end of the `with` block.

Answer (score 2):

You're subclassing the wrong thing and missing an `__enter__` method.  You probably want this:

```
class contextShelf(shelve.shelve):
  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace):
    self.close()
```

Because you're adding methods, but not changing the `__init__` signature or adding any extra steps there's no reason you need to redefine `__init__`.  The base class' `__init__` will be called automatically.

Comment: `type` is a builtin; you should not use it as a parameter name.  `traceback` is also a standard library module, and might not be a great name for a parameter, but this is less important than the former.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - True.  I'll adjust the parameter names to `__exit__`.

Comment: With `contextlib.closing()` the object returned is an instance of the desired type, rather than an instance of a subclass, but otherwise this is basically the same: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/contextlib.py#l132