# Why is Filename not a db that the shelve module can open?

Tags: python, random, shelve

```
import random
import sys
import shelve

def get_input_or_quit(prompt, quit="Q"):
    prompt += " (Press '{}' to exit) : ".format(quit)
    val = input(prompt).strip()
    if val.upper() == quit:
        sys.exit("Goodbye")
    return val

def prompt_bool(prompt):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
          return True
        elif val == 'no':
          return False
        else:
         print ("Invalid input '{}', please try again".format(val))


def prompt_int_small(prompt='', choices=(1,2)):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt)
        try:
            val = int(val)
            if choices and val not in choices:
                raise ValueError("{} is not in {}".format(val, choices))
            return val
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(
                    "Not a valid number ({}), please try again".format(e)
                    )

def prompt_int_big(prompt='', choices=(1,2,3)):
    while True:
        val = get_input_or_quit(prompt)
        try:
            val = int(val)
            if choices and val not in choices:
                raise ValueError("{} is not in {}".format(val, choices))
            return val
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(
                    "Not a valid number ({}), please try again".format(e)
                    )

role = prompt_int_small("Are you a teacher or student? Press 1 if you are a student or 2 if you are a teacher")
if role == 1:
    score=0
    name=input("What is your name?")
    print ("Alright",name,"welcome to your maths quiz."
            " Remember to round all answers to 5 decimal places.")
    level_of_difficulty = prompt_int_big("What level of difficulty are you working at?\n"
                                 "Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate "
                                    "or 3 for high\n")


    if level_of_difficulty == 3:
        ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    else:
        ops = ['+', '-', '*']

    for question_num in range(1, 11):
        if level_of_difficulty == 1:
            max_number = 10
        else:
            max_number = 20

        number_1 = random.randrange(1, max_number)
        number_2 = random.randrange(1, max_number)
        operation = random.choice(ops)

        maths = round(eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2)),5)
        print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
        print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)
        answer = float(input("What is your answer: "))
        if answer == maths:
            print("Correct")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)

    if score >5:
        print("Well done you scored",score,"out of 10")
    else:
        print("Unfortunately you only scored",score,"out of 10. Better luck next time")


    class_number = prompt_int_big("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")

    filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
    with shelve.open(filename) as db: # This is the effected line
        old_scores = db.get(name, [])
        old_scores.extend(score)
        db[name] =score[-3:]


    if prompt_bool("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
        for line in lines:
            print (line)
    else:
        sys.exit("Thanks for taking part in the quiz, your teacher should discuss your score with you later")

if role == 2:
    class_number = prompt_int_big("Which class' scores would you like to see? Press 1 for class 1, 2 for class 2 or 3 for class 3")
    filename = (str(class_number) + "txt")
    sort_or_not = int(input("Would youlike to sort these scores in any way? Press 1 if the answer is no or 2 if the answer is yes"))
    if sort_or_not == 1:
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        lines.sort()
        for line in lines:
            print (line)
    if sort_or_not == 2:
        type_of_sort = int(input("How would you like to sort these scores? Press 1 for scores in alphabetical order with each student's highest score for the tests, 2 if you would like to see the students' highest scores sorted from highest to lowest and 3 if you like to see these student's average scores sorted from highest to lowest"))
        if type_of_sort == 1:
            with open(filename , 'r') as r:
                for line in sorted(r):
                    print(line, end='')
        if type_of_sort == 2:
            file = open(filename, 'r')
            lines = file.read().splitlines()
            s = {lines[i]:[int(k) for k in lines[i+1:i+4]] for i in range(0,len(lines),4)}
            for i in sorted(s.keys()):
                print (i,max(s[i]))

            avg_mark = lambda name:sum(s[name])/len(s[name])
            for i in sorted(s.keys(),key=avg_mark,reverse=True):
                print (i,avg_mark(i))
        if type_of_sort == 3:
            file = open(filename, 'r')
            lines = file.read().splitlines()
            s = {lines[i]:[int(k) for k in lines[i+1:i+4]] for i in range(0,len(lines),4)}
            for i in sorted(s.keys()):
                print (i,max(s[i]))

            high_mark = lambda name:max(s[name])
            for i in sorted(s.keys(),key=high_mark,reverse=True):
                print (i,high_mark(i))
```

The shelve module part of my code is not working and I don't understand what the error is trying to say. I am trying to save the last three scores to a students name and then sort it in a variety of ways . The error comes up after the quiz is completed as a student.

Comment: "I don't understand what the error is trying to say" <- Man, you have it good. I can't even see the full error.

Comment: * After yo compete the quiz as a student the error comes up sorry

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the liiteral error text.

Comment: The error states that whatever `filename` is, it isn't a database that shelve knows how to open.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the file at `filename` and running the script again, so that the script is responsible for creating the database file in the correct format. If you ask it to open an empty file or a file that was created by some other means (e.g. CSV, JSON, etc.) then it doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: When i have done that it comes up with another error stating that filename is not defined

Comment: No, delete the actual file on your computer that has whatever name `filename` is equal to. Don't change the python code. You still need the variable.

Comment: It now says the db type could not be determined

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining clearly, so try this. Replace `shelve.open(filename)` with `shelve.open('dbfile')`. DON'T create a file (not even an empty one) called `dbfile` yourself - it is essential that the script is responsible for creating the file from scratch. After running the script the file will be created. It won't be in a human readable format and the other parts of your script where you open and process the file manually won't work. You have to either use *only* `shelve` to process the file or not use it at all.

Comment: I have done this and again it comes up with the an error:                                                     'AttributeError:_exit_'

Comment: That means you're not meant to use it directly as a context manager (i.e. in a `with` statement) because it hasn't been implemented as such. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7489828/2482744) on what to do.

Comment: Now its come up with another error saying that str has no attribute extend

Comment: That's because you're putting `score` into the database with `db[name] =score[-3:]`. So when `old_scores = db.get(name, [])` is run later, `old_scores` isn't a list, it's a `str`. Anyway, I can't debug all your problems for you. We've moved well past the issue you originally asked about and this latest problem was one you could have figured out simply by printing `old_scores` just before the error occurred (or just by looking closely at the code as I did). Please do your best to solve any further problems you have on your own, then ask a new question if you get stuck.